# Drawing tool with Overlay

Tags: overlay

I combined two plots using `Overlay`. In the output plot I want to add few modifications. Usually I right click on the plot (for `Plot` or `ListPlot`) and use the drawing tool option. But there is no such option for the output of the `Overlay`. Is there any alternative to drawing tool to modify (like adding text or arrow) a plot created by `Overlay`.

Comment: You can `Rasterize` it first.

Comment: In case you're not aware, there is also `Show`.

Comment: @amr: It seems that the `drawing tool` does not work with `show` too! :(

Answer (score 5):

There is a three-argument form of `Overlay` that allows you to specify one of the layers as the target for interactions. So if you *only* want to modify the contents of the last layer in the list of overlays, you can specify that layer as follows:

```
Overlay[{Plot[1, {x, -1, 1}], 
  Graphics[{Blue, Circle[]}]}, Automatic, 2]
```

This draws a blue circle as an overlay, and lets you subsequently move that circle around with the drawing tools. Here, the argument `2` refers to the second layer with the circle. If you replace it by `1` you'll be able to modify the `Plot` instead. Unfortunately you can't get both to be interactive at the same time.

Comment: If you really want the output to be `Graphics` with all of its parts modifiable, I'd suggest using `Inset` instead of `Overlay`.

Comment: You can make the third argument of Overlay dynamical, for example `Overlay[...Dynamic[x]]`, and by setting x=1 or x=2 edit the layer of your choice.

Comment: @andre Thanks, that does make it more flexible.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very rudimentary approach for an editing application. I'll reuse the Plot from Jens here...

Basically it shows you how to select a specific layer in your Overlay graphical object through a specific event (Right-Mouseclick for instance). You can handle this specific event to flip through the Overlay layers. From there you could do your specific manipulations with the drawing tools.

```
DynamicModule[{x = 1}, 
    EventHandler[
       Overlay[{Plot[1, {x, -1, 1}], Graphics[{Blue, Circle[]}]}, Automatic, 
       Dynamic[x]], {{"KeyDown", "x"} :> (x = x /. {1 -> 2, 2 -> 1})}]]
```

I've chosen here *KeyDown* as my event, since mouse clicks (like right mouse clicks) are already heavily overloaded and this is getting a nightmare to proper pass the events to the built-in event handlers.

The plot:

[image]

Pressing "x":

[image]

Pressing "x" again:

[image]